# android - Retrofit call void using Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, retrofit

I'm with a problem with Retrofit 2. I want to use the `Call<Void>` to make a call without handle the response body, but it doesnt work with Kotlin.

What I need to use instead of `Void`?

Comment: Have you tried `Unit` or `Nothing`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I want to use the Call to make a call without handle the response body, but it doesnt work with Kotlin

That is not true, it **does work**.

Something different must be wrong with your setup, or your test case is ill defined if you don't get the expected result.

A very simple example:

```
interface GitHub {

    @GET("/users/{username}/repos") 
    fun getUserRepos(@Path("username") username: String): Call<Void>
}

val github = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://api.github.com/")
        .build()
        .create(GitHub::class.java)

github.getUserRepos("maciekjanusz")
        .enqueue(object : Callback<Void> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Void>?, t: Throwable?) {
                // failure
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Void>?, response: Response<Void>?) {
                // success
            }
        })
```

I tried the above snippets in an Android example, using Kotlin 1.1.61 and Retrofit 2.3.0 and it works correctly - the call is executed and depending on the network availability and the overall setup, the correct `Callback` method is called.