# Platform class kotlin.Unit requires explicit JsonAdapter to be registered

Tags: java, android, kotlin, json-deserialization, moshi

In a retrofit interface I have defined a method return type as **ApiModel** **<** **Unit** **>**. but when I call the method I get the error below.

```
Platform class kotlin.Unit requires explicit JsonAdapter to be registered
```

so I tried to create my own JsonAdapter as below.

```
class UnitJsonAdapter {

    @ToJson
    fun toJson(writer: JsonWriter) {
        writer.nullValue()
    }

    @FromJson
    fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader): Unit {
        reader.close()
        return Unit
    }

}
```

but I face this error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected signature for public final void packagename.UnitJsonAdapter.fromJson(com.squareup.moshi.JsonReader).
    @FromJson method signatures may have one of the following structures:
        <any access modifier> R fromJson(JsonReader jsonReader) throws <any>;
        <any access modifier> R fromJson(JsonReader jsonReader, JsonAdapter<any> delegate, <any more delegates>) throws <any>;
        <any access modifier> R fromJson(T value) throws <any>;
```

I also tried what this [link](https://github.com/gildor/kotlin-coroutines-retrofit/issues/22#issuecomment-328345400) describes, but it seems to have no effect.

```
Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(UnitConverterFactory)
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi).asLenient())
            .build()
    

object UnitConverterFactory : Converter.Factory() {
    override fun responseBodyConverter(
         type: Type,
         annotations: Array<out Annotation>,
         retrofit: Retrofit
    ): Converter<ResponseBody, *>? {
         return if (type == Unit::class.java) UnitConverter else null
    }

    private object UnitConverter : Converter<ResponseBody, Unit> {
         override fun convert(value: ResponseBody) {
              value.close()
         } 
    }
}
```

Also this is my ApiModel class:

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class ApiModel<T>(
    val result: T,
    val error: Error
)
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by having a retrofit API that returns nothing? Do [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37116364/retrofit2-return-null-unit-in-kotlin-for-204-no-content-response) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47639290/android-retrofit-call-void-using-kotlin) help?

Comment: actually in the **ApiModel** I have other useful properties which I want to parse.

Comment: There is to be a [github issue](https://github.com/gildor/kotlin-coroutines-retrofit/issues/22#issuecomment-328345400) on this too. The `UnitConverterFactory` solution seems to be compatible with Moshi

Comment: I also tried the solution above, but it seems to have no effect.

Comment: Might be a good idea to add what you tried from that issue thread to the question as well then (including how you added the converter to Retrofit, and how you added your adapter above to Moshi)

Comment: Show your ApiModel

Comment: @EricCochran added to question.

Comment: You want to add a JsonAdapter for Unit onto your Moshi.Builder. As you have it now, Retrofit is just looking for a converter for ApiModel (which it selects your MoshiConverter for)

Comment: @EricCochran you mean that I should try creating a jsonAdapter for ApiModel<T>  ?

Comment: no, just one for Unit. and add it to your Moshi instance that you put into the Retrofit MoshiConverter factory

Comment: @EricCochran I already did that and it didn't work. I am using Any type instead of Unit now.